# Xamarin.Android : start an activity and wait for the result

Tags: c#, android, async-await, xamarin.android

I need to start an activity to ask the user to grant the app battery saving exemption. The user must respond yes to be able to continue:

Here is the -buggy- code I have so far:

```
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        while (!pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(this.ApplicationContext.PackageName))
        {
            IPopupService popupService = Locator.GetSharedInstance<IPopupService>();
            await popupService.DisplayAlertAsync(
                BusinessResources.GoToPowerSettingsTitle,
                BusinessResources.GoToPowerSettingsMessage,
                BusinessResources.Ok).ConfigureAwait(true);
            using (var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Forms.Context.PackageName)))
            {
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Because StartActivity won't wait, I'll ask the user once more than needed.

Now I've searched for a possible solution and found [ActivityTask](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/activitytask-helper-asyncawait-android/) and [ActivityController](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84221/announcing-android-activity-controller-preview).

I am confused right now. Which one should I use, provided that Xamarin Forms is on the way?

Comment: why you cant stop navigation to xamarin.forms until user grant permission?

Comment: Why you use a while statement? I would use a If statement to check the permission instead.

Comment: Because, the user must be prompted to accept the settings before proceeding further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I solved my problem by awaiting an [AsyncAutoResetEvent](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncAutoResetEvent.cs) after launching the activity:

An event is defined as well as a handshake value:

```
   private AsyncAutoResetEvent dozeStandby;
   private int dozeStandbyHandshake = nameof(dozeStandbyHandshake).GetHashCode(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

During the activity creation, I'm prompting the user to allow the settings.
Because I'm using StartActivityForResult, OnActivityResult will be called when the prompt activity finishes:

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        dozeStandby = new AsyncAutoResetEvent();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        while (!pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(this.ApplicationContext.PackageName))
        {
              IPopupService popupService = Locator.GetSharedInstance<IPopupService>();
              await popupService.DisplayAlertAsync(
                        BusinessResources.GoToPowerSettingsTitle,
                        BusinessResources.GoToPowerSettingsMessage,
                        BusinessResources.Ok).ConfigureAwait(true);
              using (var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)))
              {
                  this.StartActivityForResult(intent, dozeStandbyHandshake);
                  await this.dozeStandby.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
              }
         }
    }
```

In here I check the handshake to set the event.

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == dozeStandbyHandshake)
        {
            this.dozeStandby.Set();
        }
    }
```